# Improving my OLS Rolling Regression with lapply

Tags: r, lapply

This is the code of my rolling regression:

```
# betas from rolling regression will be in betas_rolling_250 matrix
fixed.window<-30
models<-c("A~B+E","A~B+C","A~B+D","A~B+C","A~B+F","A~B+B","A~B+F","A~B+C")
betas_rolling_250<-matrix(,nrow=length(models),ncol=250-fixed.window)
rownames(betas_rolling_250)<-models;

#Sample Matrix

sample_matrix_250<-matrix(rexp(10, rate=.1),nrow=250, ncol=6)
colnames(sample_matrix_250)<-c("A","B","C","D","E","F")

for(i in 1:(length(sample_matrix_250[,1])-fixed.window)){
  for(k in 1:length(rownames(betas_rolling_250))){
    coefs<-lm(rownames(betas_rolling_250)[k],data=as.data.frame(sample_matrix_250[(221-i):(251-i),]))$coefficients[3]
    betas_rolling_250[k,i]<-coefs }
}
```

First question:

Is it possible to implement this by using lapply function?

I am asking this beacause I will have to do this 4 times. Because I have more 4 differents size dataframes: (`sample_matrix_220`, `sample_matrix_200`and `sample_matrix_180`). I dont want my code to be huge.

Ive been thinking in using list. Thats why I though about lapply function.

Is it possible?

Comment: `zoo::rollapply` is probably convenient

Answer (score 0):

Consider generalizing your setup by passing the only changed variable, matrix column size, as input parameter. Then, past list of numeric values into an `lapply` call.

Below replaces any 250 to a variable (adjust as needed). The static *models* and *fixed.window* should be assigned once outside the function.

```
get_coeffs <- function(mat_size) {
    betas_rolling <- matrix(,nrow=length(models), ncol=mat_size-fixed.window)
    rownames(betas_rolling) <- models

    sample_matrix <- matrix(rexp(10, rate=.1), nrow=mat_size, ncol=6)
    colnames(sample_matrix) <- LETTERS[1:6]

    for(i in 1:(length(sample_matrix[,1])-fixed.window)){
       for(k in 1:length(rownames(betas_rolling))){
          coefs <- lm(rownames(betas_rolling)[k],
                      as.data.frame(sample_matrix[(mat_size-fixed.window)-i):(mat_size+1-i),]))$coefficients[3]
          betas_rolling[k,i] <- coefs 
       }
    }

    return(betas_rolling)
}

matrix_list <- lapply(c(180, 200, 220, 250), get_coeffs)
```